# Where on Earth can one view the entry of tiangong-1?

Tags: tiangong-1

I read a news article saying that the entry would be "spectacular" where and when can I view the entry. Will it be visible in the US?

Comment: I think we have 1.5 hours to the re-entry... which means, its location is already probably known, but it is not yet in the news.

Comment: Okay, it is fallen down into the Pacific Ocean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No-one knows for sure where it will come down: there are still wide margins on the estimates. But it's not looking likely to be the US. You can see a graphic of one estimate here (click for the latest update):

[image]

As you can see, the tracks do not go near the US in the relevant timeframe.

Comment: The ESA's final estimate of 01:00 UTC +/- 2 hours would add about half a cycle to the end of the Aerospace Corp. one, extending the green line which currently ends over the Amazon over the Atlantic, Africa, and Asia into the western Pacific.

Comment: For real time updates, look for [@Marco_Langbroek](https://twitter.com/Marco_Langbroek) and [@AerospaceCorp](https://twitter.com/AerospaceCorp), the source of this image, on twitter